# PHP - Array formated variable to real array

Tags: php, arrays

I think my problem is pretty simple, but I don't seen to figure out what is wrong.
I have a "array formatted" string that comes from a database using mysql, it comes as this:

```
"op_a" => "Text goes here,
"op_b" => "Another one",
"op_c" => "Third one"
```

But as it comes in a variable, `$foo['ops']`, I want to make it a real array. I've tried:

```
$ops = (array)$foo['ops'];
or
$ops = [$foo['ops']];
```

The result always is one row, with all the previous values in `[0]` key

```
[0] => "op_a"=>"Text goes here", "op_b"=>"Another one", "op_c"=>"Third one"
```

What should I do?

Comment: Define "real array"

Comment: It is plain text, when it comes from the database, I want to make it an array, which every "op_" is a key. op_a, op_b, op_c

Comment: Could you provide some db code. Mysql won't return a string as a result, it will almost always be an object or an array of objects, not sure how it is that you're getting a string which is an array

Comment: P.S. `json_encode($foo['ops'], true)` will convert a valid json to an associative array, you could try that.

Comment: I may not explain well, I have a table and on it I have a varchar type row, the ops row, in which have this "array formatted", to get the rows, I query and then use fetch_assoc(), and let's say the $foo['ops']. But now I wanna make this as a new real array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution, assuming - from what I understood from your question - that the entire array is coming back as a singular string, not an array of strings.

Because it's all a string, I had to deal with the double quotes, otherwise the key and value looked like: `$newarray[""key""] => ""value""`

```
$foo['ops'] = '"op_a" => "Text goes here,"op_b" => "Another one","op_c" => "Third one"'; // array returned as single string
        // separate array elements in string to temp array
        $temp = explode(',', $foo['ops']);

        // define new array to hold final values
        $newarray = [];

        // loop through temp array
        foreach ($temp as $arrElement) {
            // yet another temp array to hold key and value pair
            $t = explode('=>', $arrElement);
            // strip double quotes and trim spaces, then assign key and value to final array
            $newarray[str_replace('"', '', trim($t[0]))] = str_replace('"', '', trim($t[1]));
        }
```

The real solution would be to better format the array being stored in the db as a serialized or JSON string, so it can more easily worked with when returned from the db.  This solution is way too much work for something that should be much, much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a quote at the end of `Text goes here`.

```
$foo['ops'] = '"op_a" => "Text goes here", "op_b" => "Another one", "op_c" => "Third one"';
                                        ^
```

If you were to fix that:

```
eval('$result = array('.$foo['ops'].');');
print_r($result);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [op_a] => Text goes here
    [op_b] => Another one
    [op_c] => Third one
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Will this get you what you're after?

```
$ops = array() ;
foreach($foo['ops'][0] as $key=>$value) {
    $ops[$key] = $value ;
}
```

Comment: invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @McCormick, if `$foo['ops'][0]` is not the correct variable then replace it with the correct variable. Your original post is not clear.

Answer (score -1):

Seems a waste to store data in a RDBMS like that.
Could do this though...

```
<?php
$s = '"op_a" => "Text goes here, "op_b" => "Another one", "op_c" => "Third one"';
$tmp = explode(',', $s);
$array = [];
foreach ($tmp as $v) {
    $t = explode('=>', $v);
    $array[$t[0]] = $t[1];
}
var_dump($array);
```

Until your value contains a comma and it all comes crashing down.

Comment: At least yours accounts for the extra quotes, @JonathanEltgroth

Comment: Great minds ;) I'll gladly collaborate with you because you can pick a variable name!... Seriously downvote? Learn to read sarcasm folks...